# Draw Line on Firebreath Plugin

Tags: firebreath

I want to draw line on Firebreath Plugin. While searching I have came acrossed this [Link](https://github.com/firebreath/FireBreath/blob/master/examples/FBTestPlugin/FBTestPlugin.cpp) where FB::Rect is used to display text. I also tried for FB::Line but not available. Should I  use [D2D1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317121%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with Firebreath?
Please let me know for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not sufficiently read the code to understand what is going on.  FB::Rect is just a structure containing dimentions.  Drawing in FireBreath is just using the appropriate platform APIs to draw.  On windows that means GDI.  Learn to draw a line using GDI and you'll be able to draw with FireBreath on windows.